# Is the integral of two non-equal functions, non-equal again?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Consider two continuous and well-behaved functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, such that $\forall x \in [a,b] f(x) \neq g(x)$. What can we say about the relationship between $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ and $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx$? I am inclined to say $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx \neq \int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx$ , but I am not sure. I understand, for instance, if $f(x)=\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)$ (certainly $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for some $x$) then $\int_{0}^{2\cdot \pi} \sin(x) = \int_{0}^{2\cdot \pi} \cos(x) = 0$; however $\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ for some $x$ in $[0, 2\pi]$, for instance at $x=\pi/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, by the intermediate value theorem.

If $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$, then $\int_a^b f(x) > \int_a^b g(x)$. It follows that, if $\int_a^b f(x) = \int_a^b g(x)$, then there must be some point $x_1$ with $f(x_1) \le g(x_1)$, and symmetrically (swapping the roles of $f$ and $g$) some point $x_2$ with $f(x_2) \ge g(x_2)$. By the intermediate value theorem, there must be some point $x_3$ in between $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $f(x_3) = g(x_3)$.

Comment: I just want to add that the assumption $f(x) > g(x)$ for any $x \in [a,b]$ for this to work is VERY important. For instance, take $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 2-x$ on $[0,2]$. Observe that $\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{2}g(x)dx=2$.

Comment: @Evan William Chandra: This is not a counterexample, since $f(1) = g(1) = 1$. Since $\forall x \in [a,b] f(x) \neq g(x)$, we must have either $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ or $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: @Nathaniel Mayer thanks! It makes sense.